# Rails Sign_in(user) not working - remember_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication

I'm trying to allow my users to sign in and I have narrowed my problem to one method.

in session_helper.rb

```
def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
end

def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
end
```

How do I check what my current column structure is in my database and make fix this issue?

If a user signs in, it gives a positive flash response.

sessions_controller.rb

```
    def new
end
def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        sign_in user
        flash[:success] = 'Signed in'
        redirect_to user
    else
        flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

but it still returns signed_in? as false.
Any ideas?

Comment: how are you expecting current_user to be available in signed_in? method. Have you considered using any gem to handle login for ex- devise

Comment: I'm doing the Rails Tutorial - Michael Hartz. It should set the current_user to the user. and thus be signed in.